# Intercept C function call from Python

Tags: python, c

Is there a way to intercept a C function call on a binary (e.g: write to a file) in Python?

I need to execute the binary on Linux from python and capture the output that it writes to the log file. The log file name is unpredictable.

Comment: What do you mean by intercept? How this program run? You can launch it (using subprocess) in your Python code and get the output, is this what you want?

Comment: Can you not just read from the log file? (equivalent to `tail -f log.txt`)

Comment: Too broad... you need to refine your question, what platform etc.

Comment: On Unix you could possibly use fifo, a named pipe instead; or many programs happily write to standard output if asked nicely.

Comment: The program does write to stdout, but also to a log file. I need to "capture" that and prevent it from writing to that log file. The binary in question is out of my control. I didn't write it.

Comment: Your best bet would be to `LD_PRELOAD` (assuming Linux/ELF) a compiled library which overrides the various `fopen` or `open` functions.

Comment: What if the binary was statically linked?

Comment: @hso, it's probably not statically linked against `libc`, that's pretty rare.

Comment: if you link statically, then you link normally against every lib.

Comment: Then need to use ptrace or something, this would get tricky :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is to create a named pipe. If `logfile` is the name of your logfile:

```
import os
import subprocess

LOGFILE = 'somefile.log'

if not os.path.exists(LOGFILE):
    os.mkfifo(LOGFILE)
proc = subprocess.Popen([YOUR_PROGRAM])
with open(LOGFILE) as log:
    data = log.read()  # process your data

proc.wait()
```

Comment: But I can't know `LOGFILE` beforehand :/

Comment: you can't give the name of the logfile? how it is determined?

Comment: The program writes to a random filename in a log directory